# Why postgresql recognize only numbers in full text search?

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, full-text-search

I learn full text search in postgresql and I need to make english dictionary with FTS. I made dictionary mydict_en. I calculate words with my dictionary and other case with simple dictionary.

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY mydict_en (
   TEMPLATE = ispell,
   DictFile = english,
   AffFile = english,
   StopWords = english
);


CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.mydict_en (PARSER = default);


ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict_en ADD MAPPING 
   FOR email, url, url_path, host, file, version,
   sfloat, float, int, uint,
   numword, hword_numpart, numhword
WITH simple;


ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict_en ADD MAPPING 
   FOR word, hword_part, hword
WITH mydict_en;
```

My test table (I add FTS field):

```
CREATE TABLE matches
(
  id Serial NOT NULL,
  opponents Varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  metaKeywords Varchar(2048),
  metaDescription Varchar(1024),
  score Varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  primary key (id)
);


ALTER TABLE matches ADD COLUMN fts tsvector;
```

When I insert data to this table, for example:

```
INSERT INTO matches (opponents, metaKeywords, metaDescription, score)
VALUES ('heat - thunder', 'nba, ball', 'Heat plays at home.', '99 - 85');
```

I update my fts field based on priority:

```
UPDATE matches SET fts = 
 setweight( coalesce( to_tsvector('mydict_en', opponents),''),'A') ||
 setweight( coalesce( to_tsvector('mydict_en', metaKeywords),''),'B') ||
 setweight( coalesce( to_tsvector('mydict_en', metaDescription),''),'C') ||
 setweight( coalesce( to_tsvector('mydict_en', score),''),'D');
```

And my fts contain this record:

```
'85':2 '99':1
```

Why it contain only numbers, where are words?

Comment: Please *always* disclose the version of Postgres you are working with.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Version - "PostgreSQL 9.5.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 32-bit"